# ADO.NET DbContext Generator template missing

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, ado.net

My ADO.NET DbContext Generator is missing in VS 2012. Only the `EF 5.x DbContext Generator` appears there.

Do I need to install EF 4.1 to get ADO.NET DbContext Generator?

Comment: What's wrong with `EF 5.x DbContext Generator`?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use Nuget.

Try Tools-> Library Package Manager -> Manage Nuget Packages for a solution.